# Which tense should I use to describe my work experience?

Tags: tense

If I say:

> I work at XYZ pvt limited as a Senior Executive. I have been working there since 2011.

Is this line correct?

Which tense should I use for introducing myself during the interview?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I work at XYZ pvt limited as a Senior Executive. I have been working there since 2011

The sentence is correct, you can say:

"I have been working there (/with XY) for 4 years/ since 2011"